# SSH from Windows with PuTTY connection refused after execute the 'init 0' command

Tags: windows, ssh, centos, putty

What I have done:

1. Installed CentOS 7 in the VMware.
2. Connected to it using PuTTY from Windows at the first time.
3. Executed the `init 0` command in the PuTTY.
4. Started CentOS.
5. Tried connecting to it with PuTTY again and the following message appeared: [image: ErrorBox from PuTTY]

I have tried multiple ways, but it still won't connect.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off topic on Stack Overflow, and has already been re-posted on Super User: http://superuser.com/q/1050023/213663

Answer (score 1):

if by VMware you mean within or under Windows, like you would do Windows XP mode under Windows 7, I think being a virtual program there is no way to power back on Centos.  you would have to reinstall CentOS.  Because `init 0` in linux is the shutdown and power off command.  When you do that on a physical system you would have to push the power on button after doing that.  FYI, `init 6` is reboot.
I have messed up the winxp virtual client in Windows 7 to where it would not start and this reminds me of that.  hope that helps.

Comment: I encountered the same problem on a physical system.